# Libgdx drawing bezier curve

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to draw a bezier curve with libgdx.

```
    Vector2 pixel0 = Line.CalculateBezierPoint(0, p0, p1, p2, p3);
    System.out.print(pixel0.x);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(pixel0.x);
        float t = i / (float) 10;
        Vector2 pixel1 = Line.CalculateBezierPoint(t, p0, p1, p2, p3); //after this line pixel0 equals pixel1, why?
        //batch.draw(rect, pixel.y, pixel.x, 3, 3);
        //shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(2);
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(255,255,255,255);
        shapeRenderer.line(pixel0, pixel1);

        shapeRenderer.end();
        pixel0 = pixel1;

    }

public class Line {
    public static Vector2 CalculateBezierPoint(float t, Vector2 p0, Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, Vector2 p3) {
        float u = 1 - t;
        float tt = t*t;
        float uu = u*u;
        float uuu = uu * u;
        float ttt = tt * t;

        Vector2 p = p0.scl(uuu);
        p.add(p1.scl(3 * uu * t));
        p.add(p2.scl(3 * u * tt));
        p.add(p3.scl(ttt));

        return p;
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if pixel0 = pixel1 exist or no. Every time pixel0 is wrting by pixel1, but how, and why?

edit;
working code:

```
    Vector2 pixel0 = new Vector2(Line.CalculateBezierPoint(0, p0, p1, p2, p3));
    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        float t = i / (float) 2;
        Vector2 pixel1 = new Vector2(Line.CalculateBezierPoint(t, p0, p1, p2, p3));
        //batch.draw(rect, pixel.y, pixel.x, 3, 3);
        //shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(2);
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(255,255,255,255);
        shapeRenderer.line(pixel0, pixel1);

        shapeRenderer.end();
        pixel0 = pixel1;

    }
```

CalculateBezierPoint is a static function, i tried to deklare new function every time, and it's worked.
But now it's drawing simple line, not curve.
I used: http://devmag.org.za/2011/04/05/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/
And converted CalculateBezierPoint function to Java. Could someone check, if i have done it good?

Comment: You might want to check this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Path-interface-%26-Splines here's an example: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/PathTest.java and here's the Bezier: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Bezier.html

Comment: Probably your handling of Vectors is the problem. `Vector2 p = p0.scl(uuu);`. Vector2.scl() scales the vector, and retuns itself after that. After two iterations pixel0, pixel1 and p0 all point to the same Vector2 and will always be the same. Try using `Vector2.cpy()`